# How to fix it(Activity Reload When Data is change in Firebase) in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using dialog box in recyclerview when I click ok data is change in firebase correctly but it reloads activity again. I search and try all answers but no one works.

```
    void data(){
    db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            list.clear();
            if(!dataSnapshot.hasChildren()){
                TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.te);
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if(ds.exists()){
                        String busNumber=ds.child("BusNumber").getValue().toString();
                        String busEmail=ds.child("email").getValue().toString();
                        String id=ds.child("Id").getValue().toString();
                        String pushDriver=ds.child("pushDriver").getValue().toString();
                        String pass=ds.child("password").getValue().toString();
                        AssignModel viewAllBusModel=new AssignModel(busNumber,busEmail,pass,id,pushDriver);
                        list.add(viewAllBusModel);
                    }
                }
                assignAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    db.keepSynced(true);
}
```

**adapter class:**

```
           viewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent intent = ((Activity) context).getIntent();
            final DatabaseReference db= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("NewBus");
            final DatabaseReference asgn= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("DriverData");

            // check if this bus is not assign to anyone yet
            final String NewBus=item1.getId();
            final String  NewDriver=item1.getPushDriver();
            final String backBus=intent.getStringExtra("busId");
            final String backdriver=intent.getStringExtra("Driverpush");
            //if driver is not assign any bus and bus is not assign to driver

            if(backBus.equals("not assign") && NewDriver.equals("not assign")){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setTitle("Do you Want to Assign");
                builder.setCancelable(false)
                        .setMessage("press yes to Assign")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Toast.makeText(context,backBus +" 1"+NewDriver,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                HashMap<String,Object> data1=new HashMap<>();
                                data1.put("busId",NewBus);
                                asgn.child(backdriver).updateChildren(data1);
                                HashMap<String,Object> data=new HashMap<>();
                                data.put("pushDriver",backdriver);
                                db.child(NewBus).updateChildren(data);
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });
                AlertDialog a=builder.create();
                a.show();
            } //if driver is assign by bus and bus is assign to  other driver
            else if(!NewDriver.equals("not assign") && !(backBus.equals("not assign"))){
                Toast.makeText(context,NewDriver +" 2"+backBus,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.assign_alert);
                final TextView cancel=dialog.findViewById(R.id.can);
                TextView ok=dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);
                final TextView alert=dialog.findViewById(R.id.alert);
                alert.setText("Driver has assign to someOther bus and Bus has assign to other driver already. If you want to change Press Ok");
                cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        HashMap<String,Object> data=new HashMap<>();
                        data.put("busId","not assign");
                        asgn.child(NewDriver).updateChildren(data);

                        // NewBus=>pushDriver => not assign
                        HashMap<String,Object> dat=new HashMap<>();
                        dat.put("pushDriver","not assign");
                        db.child(backBus).updateChildren(dat);


                        // Driverdata => busId=> busId
                        HashMap<String,Object> data1=new HashMap<>();
                        data1.put("busId",NewBus);
                        asgn.child(backdriver).updateChildren(data1);

                        HashMap<String,Object> dat8=new HashMap<>();
                        dat8.put("pushDriver",backdriver);
                        db.child(NewBus).updateChildren(dat8);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
}
```

Expected output it right but only problem is activity reloads every time

Comment: probably you are starting activity while opening dialog box

Comment: When I click dialog box yes button then activity reloads I don't know why

Comment: I don;t know why this happening but it sometimes work fine sometime not what should do?